# Laravel Eloquent - Can I use an array as the list of columns for INSERT statement?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am creating a virtual shop website and I'm trying to do a Product register page.

Some of the fields from the product form are not required, so **I need a way to make my Controller only add the columns that match the received inputs.**

I've tried doing it with an associative array, where `["column-name"=>"column-input"]`, but when I try to run the query, Laravel considers all of the array rows as different insert queries with only the first column of the DB, like this:

```
SQL: insert into `produtos` (`nome`) values (Smartphone Samsung Galaxy A34 128GB), (Marca:Samsung Modelo:Galaxy), (1),[...]
```

The desired behaviour would be along the lines of:

```
SQL: insert into `produtos` (`nome`,`descricao`,`ativado`,[...]) values ("Smartphone Samsung Galaxy A34 128GB","Marca:Samsung Modelo:Galaxy", 1,[...])
```

Here is the Controller code:

```
    public function insert($post){
        $campos = Array();   // fields array
        foreach($post as $key=>$value){
            array_push($campos,[$key=>$value]);
        }

        $query = DB::table('produtos')->insert($campos);
        return $campos['url'];
    }
```

Is there any way I can achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

The create method in Laravel's Eloquent ORM is a convenient way to create a new model instance and persist it to the database

```
Produtos::create($campos);
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert data into the `produtos` table after validating the input, you can use Laravel validation in combination with the DB::table insert method.

```
public function insert($post){
  $campos = Array();    
  foreach($post as $key=>$value){
      array_push($campos,[$key=>$value]);
  }

  $data = $this->validateForm(new Request($campos));
  DB::table('produtos')->insert($data);
  return $campos['url'];
}
```

the validation function will be like below. update the fields with necessary validations that laravel has provided. to know more about validation laravel doc https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#working-with-validated-input

```
    public function validateForm(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->validate($request, [
            'nome'           => ["required"],
            'descricao'      => ["required"],
            'ativado'        => ["required"],
        ]);
    }
```